# Pandas Percentage Drop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My question is probably trivial, but I cannot figure it out. In pandas dataframe, I have `time` column and `value` column:

[image: dataframe]

I just need to add the column 'reset' that holds initial highest (max) 'value' until the 'value' has dropped by more than 10%, and then reset to that new 'value' until it has dropped by 10%, and so on. I tried grouping with true/false, but it does not work as it does not reset 'value' correctly.

```
df['action'] = np.where(df['value'] < df.value.cummax() * 0.9, True, False)
df['reset'] = df.groupby(df['action'].cumsum())['value'].cummax()
```

Any help will be truly appreciated.

Comment: Sorry I made mistake in initial question - I want to hold highest running (max) value (not just the first value), until it has dropped 10%, and so on.

Comment: You can [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66594733/edit) your post to correct any mistakes.

Comment: Ok thanks, I edited my post. Hope it is clear now